# Can not set Stock in Magento 1.9.2.4

Tags: magento, product, stock

When i try to set the **setStockData** it does not give an error but the stock is not set.

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

$product->setStoreId(1)
->setAttributeSetId(4)
->setTypeId('simple')
->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now'))
->setSku($postdata['article'])
->setName($postdata['name'])
->setStatus(1)
->setTaxClassId(2)
->setWeight(4.0000)
->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
->setCountryOfManufacture('NL')
->setPrice($postdata['price_advice'])
->setCost($postdata['price'])
->setMsrpEnabled(1) 
->setMsrpDisplayActualPriceType(1)
->setMsrp($postdata['price_advice'])
->setStockData(array(
        'use_config_manage_stock' => 0,
        'manage_stock' => 1, 
        'min_sale_qty' => 1,
        'max_sale_qty' => 2,
        'is_in_stock' => 1,
        'qty' => 100
    )
)
->setMetaTitle($postdata['name'])
->setMetaKeyword($postdata['name'])
->setMetaDescription($postdata['description'])
->setDescription($postdata['description'])
->setShortDescription($postdata['description'])
->setMediaGallery (array('images'=>array (), 'values'=>array ()))
->setCategoryIds(array($postdata['category']));
```

There is no error but when i go to the product tab in the admin panel the manage stock is still at no and nothing is updated.

When i try to set the stock after i added the product first i am getting the following error:

> Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]:
>   Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row:
>   a foreign key constraint fails (`cataloginventory_stock_item`,
>   CONSTRAINT
>   `FK_RSWW_CATINV_STOCK_ITEM_PRD_ID_RSWW_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN
>   KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_)'

Hope someone can help me with this can not figure out what i am doing wrong.
Already did a database health check no problems there.

Searched for old products with no References but als did not find any there.

Comment: Can you set stock data the same way as other values? e.g. ->setData( 'use_config_manage_stock', 0)